# How to understand the java Path.toString() method

Tags: java, java-io

**My codes:**

```
Path uploadPath = Paths.get("D:\\0.hzg\\");
System.out.println(uploadPath);
```

**output:**

```
D:\0.hzg
```

How to understand the design of the `toString()` method of `Path` here?

I thought it should output `D:\0.hzg\` since `0.hzg`is a path instead of a file.

---

update：

```
        System.out.println(Paths.get("-","A", "B")); 
        System.out.println(Paths.get("/","A", "B")); 
        System.out.println(Paths.get("\\","A", "B"));
```

outputs：

```
-\A\B
\\A\B\
\\A\B\
```

Comment: Whether you write `D:\0.hzg` or `D:\0.hzg\ ` doesn’t change whether the denoted path is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

`Path` does not do any `I/O` to check if this is a directory or a regular file. It is an utility class for working with platform dependent string representation of filesystem path (you definitely do not want to split strings by `/` or find the drive letter by yourself). Citing javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toString()

> An object that may be used to locate a file in a file system. 
>   It will typically represent a system dependent file path.

Also, trailing separators are not.taken into account (see e.g. `endsWith` method description)

> Note that trailing separators are not taken into account, 
>   and so invoking this method on the Path"foo/bar" with the
>    String "bar/" returns true.

Answer (score 1):

[Paths] gets method only creates path by taking care **system-file-separator** which will helps in cross platform execution of programs
e.g.

```
System.out.println(Paths.get(File.separator,"A", "B"));
```

will returns

On Windows : \\A\B\

On Unix : /A/B/

Details of **File.separator**  are

*The system-dependent default name-separator character. This field isinitialized to contain the first character of the value of the systemproperty file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of thisfield is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.*

**Specific to question asked**

i believe it is because of Absolute Path
e.g. on windows JDK 1.7

```
System.out.println(Paths.get("C:","A", "B")); **Output** : C:\A\B
System.out.println(Paths.get("C:","A", "0.hzg")); **Output** : C:\A\0.hzg


System.out.println(Paths.get(File.separator,"A", "B")); **Output** : \\A\B\
System.out.println(Paths.get(File.separator,"A", "0.hzg")); **Output** : \\A\0.hzg\
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: Maybe t is decided by the underlying OS?